# Call function from outside

Tags: node.js

I am using this code to create a server that listens on a specific port and ip

```
function notifier() {

        var net = require('net');
        var host = 'x.x.x.x';
        var port = xxxx;

        var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
            socket.on('data', function (data) {
                console.log("data " + data.toString());
            });

            socket.on('close', function (data) {
                console.log('closed');
            });

            socket.on('error', function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

        });

        function startServer() {
            server.listen(port, host, function () {
                console.log('started');
            });
        }

        function stopServer() {
            server.close(function () {
                console.log('stopped');
            });
        }

        startServer();
    }
```

I have also created a startServer and stopServer function.

If I call the function notifier() then the server starts but I cant figure out how I should call the stopServer function outside the function notifier()

Maybe I have made a huge mistake here and that I cant call it elsewhere, then maybe someone could point me in the right direction how it should be done correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 'notifier()' function as a factory method and return an interface object to communicate with the server instance, something like this...

```
function notifier() {

    var net = require('net');
    var host = 'x.x.x.x';
    var port = xxxx;

    var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
        // ... omitted for brevity
    });

    return {
        startServer() {
            server.listen(port, host, function () {
                console.log('started');
            });
        },
        stopServer() {
            server.close(function () {
                console.log('stopped');
            });
        } 
    }
}

let server = notifier();
server.startServer();
server.stopServer();
```

Comment: Great solution to return multiple functions.
And this solution will also work with `var self = this` and then `self.server.startServer;`?

Comment: @KristofferIsaksson it depends on the context. However, ES6 now has [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that completely remove the need to keep a reference to `self = this`

Comment: I have now switched to your solution and it worked just perfect even without the need of `var self = this`.

Answer (score 1):

Sincé in JavaScript functions are first class you can return stopServer to call it from elsewhere.

```
function notifier(){
 function stopServer(){
      ....
 }
 return stopServer; // note that we do not call the function, just return it
}

var x = notifier();
x(); // calls stopServer
```

Comment: When I try to call x from
`this.on('close', function () {
   subscribeTimer.forEach(function (timer) {
    clearInterval(timer);
   });

   x();  
  });` 
Then i receive this error: TypeError: x is not a function

Comment: @KristofferIsaksson you have a problema with the context of `this`. Because inside the anonymous function `this` refers to the anonymous function itself. Not the same this you used with `this.on`. There are ways to do what you're trying to do. One is declaring from the outside `var self = this;` and inside the anonymous function call `self.x`.

Comment: I tried that suggestion with declaring outside `var self = this;` and use `self.x`
But that gives me the same error: TypeError: self.x is not a function
Do you have any idea what is causing this behavior?

Ahh sorry, I was still using `self.x()` instead of `self.x` and now it seems to work just fine.
Thanks.

By the way, if you have the time to explain why () was causing the issue, please do.

Comment: I think I was a little to fast here.
If I use `self.x()` then I receive error message: TypeError: self.x is not a function.
But if i change to self.x then no error but it does not call the function.
So I need some more help here.